# Add a 301 redirect to redirect all traffic from one domain to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Could anyone help?

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from an old domain (with multiple subdomains and URL) to a new domain using .htaccess .
I just want to redirect traffic from all existing links (old domain) to the English subdirectory of the new domain.

I would like to know if this line is correct?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/en [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and kudos for nice question where you have shown your efforts in form of your code/rules. I would like to ask 2 questions here please. **1st:** When you put these rules and try your urls what happens then? **2nd:** Put some sample URLS eg: `http://localhost:80/en/singh/` etc FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect, mentioning this will make your question more clear, thank you and keep it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule you implemented is "correct" in that it should work *if some preconditions are met* ...

I would simplify it a bit, though:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com/en [R=301,L]
```

In case the old and the new domain are served from separate locations or even separate systems you can further simplify that by leaving away the condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com/en [R=301,L]
```

In general such rules are best implemented in the central http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that (read: if you are using a cheap hosting provider) you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (often called ".htaccess"). In that case you need to enable that feature (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation of the http server) and you need to place that file in the http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder and take care that it is readable by the http server.

And a side note: in your implementation you redirect to the unencrypted http protocol. That really is outdated these days, you really should use the encrypted https protocol. Sure, you need a valid certificate for that, but those are free these days.